# What items increase spell DC, for enchantments in particular?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, equipment, difficulty-class

I was curious what **items** are available in pathfinder that increase the save DC of a wizard's spells. If it makes a difference, I'm looking for things that increase the DC of enchantment spells.

I'm not looking for items that increase intelligence in general (e.g. headband of vast intellect)

Comment: If the question is clarified to exclude magic items that simply increase the wizard's Intelligence, I'm certain the site can accommodate this very short list.

Comment: That's really what I was looking for. I figured it wasn't that broad a question because I was only looking for items but I guess there might be a lot that increase it passively like the headband.

Answer (score 2):

A [Headband of Vast Intelligence](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-vast-intelligence) will up your spell save DCs by virtue of raising your INT. Otherwise I don't know of any items that will up your DCs. There are a few feats and racial abilities.